# How to remove axis path/line during transition in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In this [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/r8vAvjVwE2C5g3NBNvov?p=preview) I'm calling a `customYaxis` function to remove `.domain` and to add some css styling.

```
  function customYAxis(g) {
    g.call(yAxis)
    g.select(".domain").remove();
    g.selectAll("line")
      .attr("stroke", "#777")
      .attr("opacity", .5);
  }
```

But during the transition the domain reappears briefly and then it's removed again.

I know that you can achieve the same effect using only css but I'd like to know if there is a way to make sure that the domain stays removed using this custom function or if there's another way using only javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the axis generator, a black line (actually, a `<path>`) with a class named `domain` is automatically created. Have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/a329626cdf632a1af61b7124873b70c04c42b6a8/src/axis.js#L63):

```
path = path.merge(path.enter().insert("path", ".tick")
    .attr("class", "domain")
    .attr("stroke", "#000"));
```

Therefore, what you're seeing right now is the expected behaviour: the path will briefly appear before disappearing.

The best approach, and the most used one in D3 codes, is simply hiding the path with CSS:

```
.axis--y path {
  stroke: none;
}
```

Here is the updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/eY9gimuT6YI3Can679Bj?p=preview

EDIT:

Actually, there is a way to avoid CSS: use the `start` listener in the transition:

```
g.selectAll(".axis.axis--y").transition()
    .duration(durations)
    .call(customYAxis)
    .on("start", function(){
        g.select(".axis--y .domain").remove();
    })
```

In my opinion this is a very ugly solution but if fulfils your requirement of not using CSS.

Here is the new Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Hc9dl5A7KSF3Q7MtuoKA?p=preview

Comment: @RobertAndersson I edited the answer with a non-CSS solution. I don't like it, but it's up to you... I'd use CSS.

Comment: Oh sweet, may I ask you why you don't like it?

Comment: Because it's cumbersome, it keeps painting and removing elements from the SVG, it's not idiomatic... setting a simple CSS rule that works instantly is way better (in my opinion).

Comment: Well I can't argue with that, thanks for all yor help!